# Total sum for values using aggregate between two collections in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a two MongoDB collection.

`Purchase`

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    paymentId:a1,
  },
 {
   _id: 2,
   paymentId:a2,
 }
]
```

`Payment`

```
[
  {
    _id: a1,
    "paidAmountInfo" : {
        "forSeller" : 30.72,
    },
  },
 {
   _id: a2,
   "paidAmountInfo" : {
        "forSeller" : 20.72,
    },
 },
{
   _id: a3,
   "paidAmountInfo" : {
        "forSeller" : 10.72,
    },
 }
]
```

I am looking for the total sum amount of `forSeller` using MongoDB aggregation. How can I do that?

Here two paymentIds match(a1, a2). So the total sum would be (30.72 + 20.72) = 53.44

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sSq-Ocd9Q-8) what you are looking for?

Comment: No. I want to calculate the total from the Purchase table using populate the Payment table.  In Purchase table `paymentId` is the relationship id.

Comment: maybe [this?](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70226033)

Comment: No. I am looking for the total sum of `forSeller` with related id. I updated my info.